# Embedding dynamically an object with javascript

Tags: javascript, embed, tableau-api

I'm trying to **dynamically** add an embed code into an HTML page at run time using javascript, but when I add it **nothing is shown**.

The object I want to embed is a report from **Tableau Server**. If I put the code directly in the HTML page is correctly displayed (you can try yourself uncommenting the div static-container in the fiddle), but if I use javascript to add the report it fails:

```
document.getElementById('dynamic-container').innerHTML ='<div class="tableau-report-viewer">' + decodeURIComponent(data[0].TableauCode.replace(/\+/g, '%20')) + '</div>';
```

After running the above script I can see that the code is correctly added to the DOM.

Please note that the function is called after an ajax call has retrieved the data object (stored as a js variable in the example). The DOM is fully loaded when the function is called.

here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1mknywt5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tableau script will not load when you use update the innerHTML of the div, because the browser tries to prevent a cross site scripting attack. You have to preload the script, and then you code will work (You may also want to remove the script tag from the json). In your example it will be something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://analytics.wfp.org/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js'></script>
<h2>Hello world</h2>
<div id="dynamic-container"></div>
<hr/>
```

You will find a better explanation about why you cannot inject tags using innerHTML in the following link under **Security Considerations** section:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML